# How to modify a text file by inserting/changing characters in the middle?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that modifies certain text in a text file. I want it to write to a different file not append the old file. The .replace function does not work because I'm not replacing a certain word with another word. I'm doing math operations to a certain part of the file, then I want the new file to contain the new information.

I tried reading each line, looping through the lines and writing the code I want by slicing the line, but its not working. The code does not change anything in the text file.

This is the code:

```
filename = "timetag.txt"
fileout = "converted_timetag.txt"

old = open(filename,'r')
lines = old.readlines()
new = open(fileout,'w')

for line in lines:
    time = int(line[6:15])*20
    newlines = [str(line[:6]) + str(time) + "\n"]
    new.write(newlines)

old.close()
new.close()
```

Comment: Show us the code, or we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, I just did

Comment: So does `converted_timetag.txt` contain the same contents as the original `timetag.txt`? I recommend reading [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips ond ebugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `newlines = [str(line[:6]) + str(time) + "\n"]` you use the `[ ]`, which attempts to make newlines into a `list`. This gives an error during runtime,

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list

Since `new.write(newlines)` needs to take a string, not a list.

You can fix this error by taking out the square brackets, like so: `newlines = str(line[:6]) + str(time) + "\n"`.

Your code would look like:

```
filename = "timetag.txt"
fileout = "converted_timetag.txt"

old = open(filename,'r')
lines = old.readlines()
new = open(fileout,'w')

for line in lines:
    time = int(line[6:15])*20
    newlines = str(line[:6]) + str(time) + "\n"
    new.write(newlines)

old.close()
new.close()
```

If timetag.txt contains:

```
time: 123456789
time: 100000000
time: 000000001
time: 000000002
```

The output is:

```
time: 2469135780
time: 2000000000
time: 20
time: 40
```

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, thanks for the edit, missed that in my answer!